# Using valgrind to find most intensive function?

Tags: c, valgrind

I have a program running extremely slow. Is there a way to use valgrind to find out which function I need to optimize?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) tool for valgrind, which should be part of each valgrind distribution. It runs the program in the valgrind "virtual machine" and counts the number of instructions spent in each function/line of code.
The best UI for visualizing the results is kcachegrind (part of KDE).

Advantage: It works quite well if your bottleneck is CPU-bound, as it's completely simulates the application so one gets very accurate and detailed results if CPU instructions is what interests you. If not, the results might be distorted.

Disadvantage: It's slow (like valgrind). If your problem is I/O-bound, the slow execution speed will distort the results (making I/O faster in comparison) and also influence the behavior. In such cases, a profiler taking samples is the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

No, Valgrind is a dynamic analysis tool used to flesh out memory allocation errors and thread race-conditions (among other things).

You're looking for a code profiler, such as [Luke Stackwalker](http://lukestackwalker.sourceforge.net/). I don't know of any for *NIX systems off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: lol, I thought you were kidding when you mentioned that name.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. `oprofile` is the best tool for what you want.